# cakephp-sms not working transport class not found

Tags: php, cakephp, sms, cakephp-2.7, infobip

I am trying to send sms using [cakephp-sms](https://github.com/fotografde/cakephp-sms) plugin

The documentation is quite clear and brief. I installed it using Composer in my `app/Plugin` directory. I also installed [xi-sms](https://github.com/xi-project/xi-sms) using composer. This was installed in the `Vendor` directory.  In my controller for sending sms. I included  `App::uses('CakeSms', 'Sms.Network/Sms')` and implemented an `InfobipSmsTransport` class in the `Sms/Lib/Network/Sms`. Below is my class

```
<?php

   use Xi\Sms\Gateway\InfobipGateway;

   App::uses('AbstractSmsTransport', 'Sms.Network/Sms');
   class InfobipSmsTransport extends AbstractSmsTransport {
   const INFOBIP_USER = 'XXXXX';
   const INFOBIP_PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXX';

   /**

    *
    * @param CakeSms $sms
   * @return bool Success
   */
  public function send(CakeSms $sms) {
    $gw = new InfobipGateway(
        self::INFOBIP_USER,
        self::INFOBIP_PASSWORD
    );

    $service = new Xi\Sms\SmsService($gw);

    $msg = new Xi\Sms\SmsMessage(
        $sms->message(),
        $sms->from(),
        $sms->to()
    );

    $response = $service->send($msg);

    return !empty($response);
   }
 }
?>
```

When I try to send an SMS however I get the following error
`Class "InfobipSmsTransport" not found.`. I have no idea what am doing wrong? Any clues  or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `class in the Sms/Lib/Network/Sms` - that's supposed to be a folder, not a file. Assuming that's not the error the best course of action is to debug where the class isn't being found. Uou may find it useful to debug [the App::load](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/lib/Cake/Core/App.php#L563-L569) function - e.g. print the file varaible from this line `if (file_exists($file)) {` and compare the paths being checked for your class to where you've put it - You'll probably find they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CakeSms class was not loading the plugin. This is the line of code where it was failing.
  `App::uses($transportClassname, $plugin . 'Network/Sms');`.

In my `app/Config/sms.php` I just changed this `'transport' =>'Infobip'` to
  `'transport' =>'Sms.Infobip'`.  The plugin is now being loaded properly and the class is found.